# Which key is used for encryption of already sent and stored encrypted e-mails?

Tags: email, encryption, public-key-encryption

I would like to understand how e-mail encryption works.

If I want to store my already sent encrypted e-mails, are they encrypted by my public key or private key? And which key is used to sign those messages?

Comment: This is broad. There is probably no standard for email-encryption. If you are talking about GPG/PGP; your encrypted e-mails are not encrypted by any of your keys, but with the public key of the receiver. This also means, that you can't decrypt the already encrypted e-mail ever (only the receiver, as he holds the corresponding private-key).

Comment: @sascha OO, I will trust U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), it does not depend on where you use it: email or files and etc.

Public key is used for encrypt messages. Private for decrypt and sign messages.